# How to release resources used by an API when an exception occurs in constructor?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I have a set of methods B(), B1(),... that use some of resources and a set of method C(), C1(),... that release those resources, those methods belong to an API (such as GLFW, OpenGL,...), I put them in an constructor and destructor of a class A:

```
class A {
public:
  A() {
    B();
    B1();
    ....
    throw 1;
  }
  ~A() {
     C();
     C1();
   }
};
```

And when an exception occurs, ~A() can not be called, so resources used by this API can not be released. I can not use smart pointer to ensure no memory leak, I also do not want try catch statement in constructor because of creating an useless object. Can anyone have any solution for this situation ?

Comment: [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization), always [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization). And maybe you're doing a little to much in the constructor? Perhaps your design might need a little work?

Comment: Besides, you *can* catch in the constructor, clean up, and then re-throw the exception. Not good design, but it can be done.

Comment: The d'tor isn't called because the object isn't constructed. You have a design flaw, and seem intent on avoiding all the practices the would fix it.

Comment: You can even catch (but not swallow) exceptions from the initializer list with a [function-try-block](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block).

Comment: You could do the cleanup of everything created before the exception is thrown. (At least for this simple example).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Although I generally agree with RAII being the optimal solution, it could be problematic with OpenGL since OpenGL objects are just integer handles (unless you have every OpenGL object wrapped in a C++ class object).

Comment: @BDL "(unless you have every OpenGL object wrapped in a C++ class object)" which is exactly the C++ RAII (i.e. rule of 0/5) way to do this.

Comment: @MaxLanghof: Sure. It's just not what happens in a lot of cases. Especially for small projects, the amount of OpenGL wrapper classes can easily get out of hand. I usually prefer the unique_ptr with custom deleter approach but since op said he doesn't want that, wrapping everything might be the cleanest approach.

Comment: @BDL You don't really need many wrapper classes, though. A generic wrapper of `int` with a type-erased "deleter" could work just as well.

Comment: @BDL So you do `template <void (*)(GLuint)> class OpenGLHandle { GLuint handle; ... };`. Already your C++ code will get much cleaner and simpler and safer than having cleanup functions all over.

Comment: @Aschepler: That would be a really nice addition to your answer. Learned something new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* do something like:

```
A::A() {
    B();
    try {
        B1();
        try {
            // ...
        } catch (...) {
            C1();
            throw;
        }
    } catch (...) {
        C();
        throw;
    }
}
```

but obviously, this is quite ugly.

The better way is to go even more toward the Resource Allocation Is Initialization (RAII) pattern: make sure each library initialization is represented by one C++ object.  You can keep this just as convenient by making these individual objects members of your overall `A` class.

```
class A {
public:
    A() = default;
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
    ~A() = default;
private:
    class Lib1 {
    public:
        Lib1();
        ~Lib1();
    };
    class Lib2 {
    public:
        Lib2();
        ~Lib2();
    };
    // ...
    Lib1 lib1;
    Lib2 lib2;
    // ...
}
```

Notice the constructor and destructor of `A` are now compiler-generated. In ordinary usage, C++ will initialize the members `lib1`, `lib2`, ... in order of declaration and destroy them in the reverse order.  And if any member's constructor throws an exception, C++ knows to destroy all the other members it already created as part of initializing the containing `A`.  For example, if `Lib2::Lib2()` throws, C++ will automatically call `Lib1::~Lib1()`.

Comment: Thank you, that helps me so much. I have a question: if I have an init() method in class A and put all B(),B1(),... into init(), then I call init() after creating an object of class A, this method throw exception instead of constructor, then destructor of that object is called. Can I use this ? Or Is this bad ?

Comment: @Hope That doesn't really solve anything. How will the destructor of `A` know which initializations did and didn't actually happen?  It also becomes possible for some code to catch the exception from `init`, but the `A` object still exists.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation saved me :). If I have two method for initializing, glfwInit() (for initializing library), glfwCreateWindow() (for creating context and window) and two method for releasing resources, glfwTerminate() (close library), glfwDestroyWindow() (close window, context), those method are all in GLFW library, then I need to create two class (Lib1, Lib2) inside A ?